# Revers order of XML dated programs

Tags: xslt

I was reading through he use of XSLT to reverse the order of this podcast xml file and create a new one in reverse date order.  I get the concept but dont understand how to perform this and where to place the xlst code for the reversing of this document.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0"  xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>
  <title>FOOD &amp; WINE with CHEF JAMIE GWEN</title>
  <link>http://www.chefjamie.com/</link>
  <language>en-us</language>
  <copyright>Copyright &#xA9;Tastebud Entertainment, Inc. 2018</copyright>
  <itunes:subtitle>Delicious conversation every Sunday about food and wine</itunes:subtitle>
  <itunes:author>Chef Jamie Gwen</itunes:author>
  <atom:link href="http://chefjamie.com/media/podcasts/Food-Wine-Podcasts/ChefJamie_podcast2.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
  <webMaster>johnm@splithopsbrewing.com (John Merlino)</webMaster>
  <itunes:summary>Syndicated on 70 Plus Stations across the United States and heard live every Sunday!</itunes:summary>
  <description>Explore the culinary world with Jamie and meet top chefs, master sommeliers, cookbook authors and artisan food makers. Two hours of delicious conversation weekly &#33;</description>
  <itunes:explicit>No</itunes:explicit>
  <itunes:image href="http://www.chefjamie.com/media/podcasts/Food-Wine-Podcasts/chefJamie_PodCast_image.jpg" />
  <itunes:name>Chef Jamie Gwen</itunes:name>
  <itunes:email>jamie@chefjamie.com</itunes:email>
  <itunes:owner>Chef Jamie Gwen</itunes:owner>
  <itunes:category text="Arts &amp; Food"/> 
  <itunes:category text="Arts"/>

<item>
<title>Jan 8th, 2012</title>
<enclosure url="http://www.chefjamie.com/media/podcasts/Food-Wine-Podcasts/1-8-12.mp3" length="145178121" type="audio/mp3" />
<guid>http://www.chefjamie.com/media/podcasts/Food-Wine-Podcasts/1-8-12.mp3</guid>
<pubDate>Sun, 08 Jan 2012 13:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
<category>Podcasts</category>
<itunes:author>Chef Jamie Gwen</itunes:author>
<itunes:subtitle>Wine, Dine, &amp; Balls</itunes:subtitle>
<itunes:summary>Happy New Year 2012.We are LIVE ON THE RADIO Daniel Holtzman of The Meatball Shop NYC shares melt-in-your mouth recipes for Meatballs of every kind. Sophie Gayot of www dot gayot dot com with highlights on Where to Dine in 2012.Jeff Scott, Author of Notes from a Kitchen with insight into the Culinary World.J. Lohr Winemaker Steve Peck fills our glasses with Cabernet and Pinot Noir</itunes:summary>
<itunes:explicit>No</itunes:explicit>
<itunes:duration>1:15</itunes:duration>
<itunes:keywords>food, cooking, wine, talk, cooking podcast, recipe podcast, diy cooking, learn to cook, learn new recipes, recipes, holiday, Christmas,</itunes:keywords>
</item>

<item>
<title>Jan  15th, 2012</title>
<enclosure url="http://www.chefjamie.com/media/podcasts/Food-Wine-Podcasts/1-15-12.mp3" length="47757770" type="audio/mp3" />
<guid>http://www.chefjamie.com/media/podcasts/Food-Wine-Podcasts/1-15-12.mp3</guid>
<pubDate>Sun, 15 Jan 2012 13:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
<category>Podcasts</category>
<itunes:author>Chef Jamie Gwen</itunes:author>
<itunes:subtitle>Family, Techniques, and Fitness</itunes:subtitle>
<itunes:summary>New Orleans Chef John Besh shares his Family Table. Editor Jack Bishop of Cooks Illustrated Talks about the Techniques of Home Cooking. Karen Page and Andrew Donenburg discuss their newest book on Food and Wine. Fitness Expert Lisa Lynn creates your Workout Strategy for 2012 </itunes:summary>
<itunes:explicit>No</itunes:explicit>
<itunes:duration>49:45</itunes:duration>
<itunes:keywords>food, cooking, wine, talk, cooking podcast, recipe podcast, diy cooking, learn to cook, learn new recipes, recipes, holiday, christmas,</itunes:keywords>
</item>

<item>
<title>Jan  22nd, 2012</title>
<enclosure url="http://www.chefjamie.com/media/podcasts/Food-Wine-Podcasts/1-22-12.mp3" length="18924125" type="audio/mp3" />
<guid>http://www.chefjamie.com/media/podcasts/Food-Wine-Podcasts/1-22-12.mp3</guid>
<pubDate>Sun, 22 Jan 2012 13:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
<category>Podcasts</category>
<itunes:author>Chef Jamie Gwen</itunes:author>
<itunes:subtitle>Produce, Asian Meals, and Ground Meat</itunes:subtitle>
<itunes:summary>Jamie and Lana Review the Top 10 Best Finds at The Fancy Food Show. Southern Chef Hugh Acheson on Seasonal Produce. Paul Martins American Grill Partner Brian Bennett shares his commitment to Local, Sustainable and Organic. Author Nina Simonds celebrates Chinese New Year with her "Simple Asian Meals". GM and Master Sommelier Michael Jordan LIVE from The Ranch! Jim Villas highlights the best recipes using Ground Meat for Superbowl! From his new cookbook "From The Ground Up" </itunes:summary>
<itunes:explicit>No</itunes:explicit>
<itunes:duration>01:18:51</itunes:duration>
<itunes:keywords>food, cooking, wine, talk, cooking podcast, recipe podcast, diy cooking, learn to cook, learn new recipes, recipes, holiday, Christmas,</itunes:keywords>
</item>

<item>
<title>Jan  29th, 2012</title>
<enclosure url="http://www.chefjamie.com/media/podcasts/Food-Wine-Podcasts/1-29-12.mp3" length="161118248" type="audio/mp3" />
<guid>http://www.chefjamie.com/media/podcasts/Food-Wine-Podcasts/1-29-12.mp3</guid>
<pubDate>Sun, 29 Jan 2012 13:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
<category>Podcasts</category>
<itunes:author>Chef Jamie Gwen</itunes:author>
<itunes:subtitle>Superbowl of Food, Salmon, Spices, and BBQ</itunes:subtitle>
<itunes:summary>Gridiron Grub: Lana and Jamie dish on the Superbowl of Food. Jeff Hall of Chapter One in Santa Ana highlights the Newest Artisan Spirits On The Market. Fish Farmer Stewart Hawthorne of Skuna Bay Salmon on Craft Raised Salmon. Chef Mark Garcia pumps of the Flavor of our dishes with the Flavor Forecast 2012 from McCormick Spices. Rick Browne,the King of BBQ, Smokes Us Out!  </itunes:summary>
<itunes:explicit>No</itunes:explicit>
<itunes:duration>01:23:55</itunes:duration>
<itunes:keywords>food, cooking, Superbowl, talk, cooking podcast, recipe podcast, diy cooking, learn to cook, learn new recipes, recipes, bbq, spices</itunes:keywords>
</item>

<item>
<title>Feb 5th, 2012</title>
<enclosure url="http://www.chefjamie.com/media/podcasts/Food-Wine-Podcasts/2-5-12.mp3" length="80225176" type="audio/mp3" />
<guid>http://www.chefjamie.com/media/podcasts/Food-Wine-Podcasts/2-5-12.mp3</guid>
<pubDate>Sun, 05 Feb 2012 13:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
<category>Podcasts</category>
<itunes:author>Chef Jamie Gwen</itunes:author>
<itunes:subtitle>Superbowl Sunday Show</itunes:subtitle>
<itunes:summary>Ideas and Recipes for a Winning Superbowl Party Beer Truffles. Were having a party with PJ Clarkes Chef Johnny Church He is dishing on burger blends, oysters and the best fries. Arizona Biltmores Exec Chef Todd Sicolo on Wrights Restaurant and Big Game Food. Southern Chef Hugh Acheson shares his Modern Southern Style. Rick Rodgers with Sparkling Cocktail Inspiration  </itunes:summary>
<itunes:explicit>No</itunes:explicit>
<itunes:duration>01:23:34</itunes:duration>
<itunes:keywords>food,cooking,superbowl,talk,cooking podcast,recipe podcast,diycooking,beer,truffles,superbowl</itunes:keywords>
</item>

<item>
<title>Feb 12th, 2012</title>
<enclosure url="http://www.chefjamie.com/media/podcasts/Food-Wine-Podcasts/2-12-12.mp3" length="81886563" type="audio/mp3" />
<guid>http://www.chefjamie.com/media/podcasts/Food-Wine-Podcasts/2-12-12.mp3</guid>
<pubDate>Sun, 12 Feb 2012 13:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
<category>Podcasts</category>
<itunes:author>Chef Jamie Gwen</itunes:author>
<itunes:subtitle>The Love Show</itunes:subtitle>
<itunes:summary>Spago Pastry Chef Sherry Yard gets us in the mood for love with Valentines Day Desserts. Chef Bernard Guillas of the Marine Room shares Recipes for Romance. Tanya Zuckerbrot Registered Dietitian and the creator of The F-Factor Diet divulges the Foods that you can Add To Your Diet to Lose Weight. Bake, Decorate, Celebrate! Wilton Baking Schools Nancy Siler gives us sweet Valentine Inspiration </itunes:summary>
<itunes:explicit>No</itunes:explicit>
<itunes:duration>01:25:18</itunes:duration>
<itunes:keywords>food, cooking, superbowl, talk, cooking podcast, recipe podcast, diy cooking, learn to cook, learn new recipes, recipes, sherry yard, romance, love</itunes:keywords>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Would like to take the programs and list them on another fresh xml document that can be hit showing the most recent show first.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what attempts at solving this problem you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If the items are already arranged in chronological order from oldest to newest, and you merely want to reverse the existing order, you can do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="channel">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::item)]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="item">
            <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So you had asked that I should post any relative fixes I have tried already, to this point none, I have looked at several but they just didn't make sense outside of physically moving the tags.  The code you have displayed here, how do I run that?  It is inserted in the xml file itself or do I call it from another page?

Comment: 1. I am afraid you are confusing me with someone else. 2. I thought your question was about XSLT code. If you don't know how to run a XSL transformation, then that's a radically different problem.